# Unable to establish Remote connection for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Currently I am working with PostgreSQL database. I have to access the PostgreSQl through Remote connection. For that i have already made changes in pg_hba.cong and postgresql.conf file.

Here is my pg_hba.conf file,

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32           md5

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
host all all 192.168.0.0/24 md5
host    all            all            192.168.1.28/32           md5
```

Here is my postgresql.conf file,

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directories = ''   # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)

# - Security and Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min      # 1s-600s
#ssl = off              # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
                    # (change requires restart)
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on     # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'      # (change requires restart)
#ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'       # (change requires restart)
#ssl_key_file = 'server.key'        # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ca_file = ''           # (change requires restart)
#ssl_crl_file = ''          # (change requires restart)
#password_encryption = on
#db_user_namespace = off
#row_security = on
```

Now when i am trying to connect through client machine , I am getting error like,

```
Unable to connect to server:

FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.1.28", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

Can anyone suggest me solution for this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the *remote* machine part of your 192.168.0.0 subnet? Is your local machine  behind a NAT-router?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address  See under: `Private addresses`

Comment: Yes, ip for remote machine is 192.168.1.111